# How to display text on the right and change its font style?

Tags: adjustbox

I'm writing a dedication in my report. I the last of the dedication I want to write my name on the right with different font Style.

Do some one know how to do this please ?

Comment: `\begin{flushright}<font change><Text>\end{flushright}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like

```
\cleardoublepage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\vspace*{\stretch{1}}

\begin{flushright}
To uncle Ethan

\bigskip

\footnotesize\itshape Debbie
\end{flushright}

\vspace{\stretch{2}}

\cleardoublepage
```

In the picture, frames are just to show the positioning.

[image]

I hope someone can spot the quotation. `;-)`

Comment: @pietà You're welcome! Did you spot the quotation?